# What is the intended purpose of CSV files in POSTman?

Tags: postman

I've seen no clear documentation on using CSV.  What is the intended purpose - to read in variables?

For example, i'd like to run this many times with different vars. Does CSV files let me do this?  The problem is that i cant see what my actual requests are in the collection window - i can only see the request with the var name, right?

localhost/api/{{var}}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with the CSV. If your csv was

```
var,name
1,name
2,name2
```

In collection runner if you iterate twice with localhost/api/{{var}}, the urls would be the following

1. localhost/api/1
2. localhost/api/2

Let me know if I haven't explained this well and I can add a little more detail a bit later.

Comment: yep - to debug it i needed to turn on the chome dev tools option

Comment: @glutz - yes, I use the console a lot while writing test cases.